# Calculate total hours between 2 time stamps?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, time, hour

How we can make a store procedure in between time?

like,

```
Total Hr=(( outtime - intime) - (breakin time - breakout time) )
```

Comment: Are your using C#, VB or SQL? In case you are using SQL, which engine (SQL Server, Oracle, mySql, Postgresql) and which version?

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure sp_time_outtime

@id bigint

as

begin

declare

 @totalhour as nvarchar(50),

@tth as bigint,

@ttm as bigint,

@inhour as bigint,

@outhour as bigint,

@breakinhour as bigint select @tth = datediff(mi, intime, (case when  breakouttime is null then isnull(breakintime,GETDATE()) else GETDATE() end) ) from time where empid=@id   and CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) = CONVERT(date,[date])

 select @ttm = datediff(mi, isnull(breakintime,'1/1/1990'),ISNULL(breakouttime,isnull (breakintime,'1/1/1990'))) from time where empid=@id  and CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) = CONVERT(date,[date])


 select @totalhour = (@tth -@ttm)

 SET @totalhour = CASE WHEN (@tth -@ttm) >= 60 THEN (SELECT CAST(((@tth -@ttm) / 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' :H :' +  
                CASE WHEN ((@tth -@ttm) % 60) > 0 THEN
                    CAST(((@tth -@ttm) % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' M'
                ELSE
                    ''
                END)  ELSE 
        CAST(((@tth -@ttm) % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M'
    END
 if ((select outtime from time where empid=@id and convert(date,GETDATE())=CONVERT(date,[date])) IS NULL)
begin
 update time set outtime=GETDATE(),totalhour=@totalhour where 
empid=@id and CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) = CONVERT(date,[date])
end END
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. In other case it seems a copy + paste from another one.